# Unit testing strategy for conforming to Equatable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Let's say I have a `struct` that conforms to `Equatable` for my model, something like this:

```
struct Model: Equatable {
    var a: Int = 0
    var b: String = ""
}

func ==(lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b
}
```

Now I write some unit tests for this. Something like:

```
func testModelsAreEqual() {
    let model1 = Model()
    let model2 = Model()
    XCTAssertEqual(model1, model2)
}

func testModelsAreNotEqual1() {
    let model1 = Model()
    var model2 = Model()
    model2.b = "hello world"
    XCTAssertNotEqual(model1, model2)
}

func testModelsAreNotEqual2() {
    let model1 = Model()
    var model2 = Model()
    model2.a = 1
    XCTAssertNotEqual(model1, model2)
}
```

But how can I write a test that will protect me from the scenario that another property is added to `Model` without being added to the memberwise-equality check for `==` like:

```
struct Model: Equatable {
    var a: Int = 0
    var b: String = ""
    var c: Double = 0
}

func ==(lhs: Model, rhs: Model) -> Bool {
    return lhs.a == rhs.a && lhs.b == rhs.b
}
```

Where obviously my tests will all still pass even though conceptually my `Equatable` is broken. Is there a testing strategy I could adopt here that will help alert me to this problem? Is there something I can do with Swift's `Mirror` and limited reflection? Perhaps `Mirror.children.count`? Or does anyone have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching for other solutions, I have decided to use reflection for member count to alert me of changes. Here is the test for the example above:

```
func testModelStillHas2Members() {
    XCTAssertEqual(Mirror(reflecting: Model()).children.count, 2, "The member count of Model has changed, please check the `==` implementation to ensure all members are accounted for.")
}
```

Comment: Did you find a better, less indirect solution for this issue? It's very easy to make the Equatable protocol for an adopting type wrong, and it's probably very hard to notice without the proper unit tests.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't. And judging by some other discussions I have seen on the web, there aren't any better ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is my take:

```
func testModel3() {
    let model1 = Model()
    var model2 = Model()
    model2.c = 1
    model2.p.name = "Jack"

    let mirror1 = Mirror(reflecting: model1)
    let mirror2 = Mirror(reflecting: model2)

    let prop1 = mirror1.children.reduce([String: NSObject]()) {
        (var dict, e) in
        dict[e.label!] = e.value as? NSObject
        return dict
    }
    let prop2 = mirror2.children.reduce([String: NSObject]()) {
        (var dict, e) in
        dict[e.label!] = e.value as? NSObject
        return dict
    }

    if model1 == model2 {
        XCTAssertEqual(prop1, prop2, "Not really equal")
    } else {
        XCTAssertNotEqual(prop1, prop2, "Not really diffrent")
    }
}
```

It builds 2 dictionaries with the names & values of all properties in `model1` and `model2`, then assert if these 2 dictionaries are equal.

**Big warning:** I have not thoroughly tested this. It worked for the limited number of cases I threw at it. You may have to improvise from here.

Comment: I don't think this will work if the values in the mirror aren't decedents of `NSObject` e.g. custom structs and enums.

Comment: I'm also unsure if this gets what I want, because I don't think it will catch when you add additional properties but haven't added them to the member wise equals implementation of `==`

Comment: @JackLawrence you are right. Reflection in Swift is a limited affair. It fails when the object is not convertible to `NSObject`. I'm think about how to handle these cases